# Launching JavaFxApplication from JFrame

Tags: java, javafx

I have written application in JavaFx that shows spinning RGB cube. I wont to run this application after choosing option in JMenuBar in JFrame. I tryed something like this:

```
if(e.getSource()== showRGBCube){
        cubedemo.CubeDemo.launch();
    }
```

But it throws:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class grafika1.MyMenu is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
```

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Application.launch(CubeDemo.class);
```

but note you can only execute `launch(...)` once during the lifetime of the JVM (so if the user selects your menu item a second time, it will throw an exception).

If you want to display a JavaFX user interface in a swing application, the supported way to do that is with a [`JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html), which you can place into a `JFrame` directly. So you would do something like:

```
public class CubeDemo {

    private final Parent view ;

    public CubeDemo() {
        view = new BorderPane(); // or any other kind of pane...
        // set up ui, register event handlers, etc etc
    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

You can still make a standalone JavaFX application (if you need) with:

```
public class CubeDemoApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CubeDemo cubeDemo = new CubeDemo();
        Scene scene = new Scene(cubeDemo.getView());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

and in your Swing application you can do:

```
JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(jfxPanel);
frame.setSize(...);
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    CubeDemo cubeDemo = new CubeDemo();
    Scene scene = new Scene(cubeDemo.getView());
    jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
});
frame.setVisible(true);
```